# Clojure compile time

Tags: clojure, compilation, leiningen

I'm testing out Clojure for the first time, and wanted to write a simple websocket client application. I've found the library https://github.com/stylefruits/gniazdo and got the code to work (using `lein run`). However, compiling the code into a jar (either with `lein jar` or `lein uberjar` is either stuck or takes ages (aborted after ~1h))

steps:

1. `lein new app testing`
2. modified src/testing/core.clj and project.clj (see below)
3. `lein jar` (or `lein uberjar`)

For simplicity I've have this very simple code, which already takes ages to compile into a jar:

```
(ns testing.core
  (:gen-class))

(require '[gniazdo.core :as ws])

(def socket
    (ws/connect
            "wss://some.url.com/"))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (ws/close socket))
```

project.clj:

```
(defproject testing "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [stylefruits/gniazdo "1.0.1"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot testing.core
  :aot [testing.core]
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

output of running `lein jar`:

```
$lein jar
Compiling testing.core
2017-12-11 14:15:14.813:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1352ms
```

and nothing aferwards. Is this normal behaviour (and it just takes ages to compile) or am I missing something here? Clojure looks very interesting, but if it takes even for such a small program hours to compile, deployment could be a problem in my circumstances.

Comment: Either: 1. Don't connect at the top level or: 2. Don't AOT your `testing.core` namespace. How do you think a connection should be stored in a JAR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When that namespace is compiled *Ahead of Time* (`:aot [testing.core]` in your project.clj), this code gets evaluated during compilation:

```
(def socket
  (ws/connect "wss://some.url.com/"))
```

This is likely what's causing the hang. The compiler never moves on from this because it has made a blocking call.

1. You could remove the `:aot` directive if you don't need it (and you probably don't). I think this can be a somewhat confusing default when creating a new Leiningen project.
2. You could do something like wrap that socket/conn in a [`delay`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/delay):

   ```
   (def socket (delay (ws/connect "wss://some.url.com/")))
   ```

   And then `deref`/`@` it wherever you need the value. This just *delays* evaluation of `ws/connect` until you ask.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand that correctly: AOT compilation actually executes the code, rather than creating the bytecode representing the definition of socket? In that case would that also work:

    (defn socket [url] (ws/connect url))

Comment: @Moe Yes, the only way to compile clojure code is to execute the namespace in which it resides.